# VueJS renders some v-binds in DOM (functions and data)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm using v-bind on my router view for some data objects and functions to be used in a component, some work totally expected but some others are rendered into the DOM for whatever reason, and I can't find a reason why they are rendered and others are not.

Is that normal? or how can I fix this?

F.e. userString and the function userFunction is rendered into the router view div but otherUserString is not.

```
<router-view
     v-bind:userString="userString"
     v-bind:userObject="userObject"
     v-bind:userFunction="userFunction"

     v-bind:otherUserString="otherUserString"
     v-bind:otherUserObject="otherUserObject"
     v-bind:otherUserFunction="otherUserFunction"
/>
```

And my result is as follows (broken up for readability):

```
<div
     data-v-571e686
     userstring="XXXXXX"
     useraction="function () { [native code] }"
     userobject="[object Object]" >
```

What I expected was:

```
<div data-v-571e686>
```

Comment: Probably because `encryptUser` is a function!? You can always pass functions to child components as methods of a passed in wrapper object

Comment: Well yeah, encryptUser is a function but there are other functions that are not rendered in the DOM and they work. 

I have objects and functions that are rendered in the DOM and objects and functions that are not. And I wish for all of them to be not rendered in the DOM.

What do you mean by your proposed workaround?

I updated the question with a more clearer example what I mean. That some binds get rendered others don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue Router hasn't userEncrypted and encryptUser props. https://router.vuejs.org/api/#exact-active-class

If this is your custom component then make sure that these props are defined.

Comment: So wait, I can't use v-bind on router-view? I thought I can use v-binds to pass props for the router-view the same way as on other elements?

Comment: What do you want to achieve here? How you plan to access these values after binding to router-view?

Comment: I'm accessing them via props in the different views. And if needed pass them onto other child components.

Comment: Consider using vuex or other state management tool (localStorage, global data, etc)

Comment: I'm already using localStorage to store data that is needed. However I'm not using vuex. What would be the benefit from using that in my case?

Comment: Also I know I could use vuex, but my question is rather why are some v-binds rendered in the dom and some aren't.

Comment: v-binds renders in dom if component hasnt defined exactly the same props as you use. For this case - <router-view> component doesnt have props "userEncrypted" and "encryptUser" as I already mentioned in my answer

Comment: Sorry for my late answer, I was pretty busy with something else and completely forgot this. I don't understand what you mean by it doesn't have the props "userEncrypted" userEncrypted is v-binded to <router-view> and the view inside of the <router-view> uses the prop userEncrypted.